# По клику сделать неактивные поля

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста. Как можно по клику на rudiobutton сделать все поля неактивными, т.е. чтобы туда нельзя было ввести текст. Хотелось бы на JS или jQuery это исполнить

```html
<input id="free-pickup-radio" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address"/>
   <label for="free-pickup-radio" class="checkbox">Самовывоз?</label>

<div class="shipping_address" style="display: block;">
   
<p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_address_1_field" data-priority=""><label for="shipping_address_1" class="hidden">Адрес</label><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_address_1" id="shipping_address_1" placeholder="Адрес" value=""></p>
   
    
<p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_city_field" data-priority=""><label for="shipping_city" class="hidden">Населённый пункт</label><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_city" id="shipping_city" placeholder="Населённый пункт" value=""></p>
   
    
<p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_state_field" data-priority=""><label for="shipping_state" class="hidden">Область/регион</label><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" value="" placeholder="Область/регион" name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state"></p>
   
    
<p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_postcode_field" data-priority=""><label for="shipping_postcode" class="hidden">Почтовый индекс</label><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_postcode" id="shipping_postcode" placeholder="Почтовый индекс" value=""></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pVrrGZ?editors=1000  и я тоже сделал наjQuery , но на ванили конечно лучше

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте поиск по `id` и свойство `disabled`.
Рекомендую заменить radiobutton на checkbox, так как radiobutton нельзя снять (на случай, если пользователь передумал).

```js
let inputDisable = function(value) {
  document.getElementById('shipping_address_1').disabled = value;
  document.getElementById('shipping_city').disabled = value;
  document.getElementById('shipping_state').disabled = value;
  document.getElementById('shipping_postcode').disabled = value;
}
```

```html
<input id="free-pickup-radio" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address" onchange="inputDisable(true)" checked/>
<label for="free-pickup-radio" class="checkbox">Самовывоз?</label>
<input id="free-pickup-radio" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address" onchange="inputDisable(false)" />
<label for="free-pickup-radio" class="checkbox">Не самомывоз</label>

<div class="shipping_address" style="display: block;">
  <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_address_1_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="shipping_address_1" class="hidden">Адрес</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_address_1" id="shipping_address_1" placeholder="Адрес" value="" disabled="true">
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_city_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="shipping_city" class="hidden">Населённый пункт</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_city" id="shipping_city" placeholder="Населённый пункт" value="" disabled="true">
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_state_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="shipping_state" class="hidden">Область/регион</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" value="" placeholder="Область/регион" name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" disabled="true">
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_postcode_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="shipping_postcode" class="hidden">Почтовый индекс</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_postcode" id="shipping_postcode" placeholder="Почтовый индекс" value="" disabled="true">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: а снять как тогда ? только в одну сторону работает

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё один момент. Эта кнопка по умолчанию будет checked, можно ли сделать так, чтобы и поля были такими по умолчанию? 

Т.е. будет две радиокнопки: одна блокирует поля, другая разблокирует.

Comment: @Viking777, добавил второй radiobutton, который снимает значение. По умолчанию все поля стоят со значением disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="ship_to_different_address"]', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'not') {
    $('.shipping_address input').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.shipping_address input').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

#shipping_address {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label for="without_delivery" class="checkbox">
    <input id="without_delivery" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address" value="not" checked="" />Самовывоз?
  </label>
  <label for="delivery" class="checkbox">
    <input id="delivery" type="radio" name="ship_to_different_address" value="yep" />Доставка
  </label>

  <div class="shipping_address">
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_address_1_field" data-priority="">
      <label for="shipping_address_1" class="hidden">Адрес</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_address_1" id="shipping_address_1" placeholder="Адрес" value="" disabled="true">
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_city_field" data-priority="">
      <label for="shipping_city" class="hidden">Населённый пункт</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_city" id="shipping_city" placeholder="Населённый пункт" value="" disabled="true">
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_state_field" data-priority="">
      <label for="shipping_state" class="hidden">Область/регион</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" value="" placeholder="Область/регион" name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" disabled="true">
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field form-group" id="shipping_postcode_field" data-priority="">
      <label for="shipping_postcode" class="hidden">Почтовый индекс</label>
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shipping_postcode" id="shipping_postcode" placeholder="Почтовый индекс" value="" disabled="true">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```